# How to pass parameters to UserControl from Repeater in codebehind c#

Tags: c#, user-controls, repeater

I need to loop through a collection and pass the values to a UserControl.  It's dynamic and I can't figure out how to pass the parameter values.  I'm using a repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="Repeater1">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <uc1:testControl ID="testControl1" runat="server"   />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In the code behind:

```
Repeater1.DataSource = _myCollection;
                Repeater1.DataBind();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Not sure why but the code box totally failed up above.  I tried pasting my repeater code, typing it, wrapping it quotes, and putting code tags around it.  fail.

Comment: You can highlight the code and press the **{}** button.

Comment: Man, that was driving me nuts.  Thanks for the info Justin!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ASPX code:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="Repeater1" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <uc1:testControl ID="testControl1" runat="server" /> 
    </ItemTemplate > 
</asp:Repeater>
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    testControl ctrl = e.Item.FindControl("testControl1") as testControl;

    if (ctrl != null)
        ctrl.MyParameterName = "Foo";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an event handler to the [`Repeater.ItemDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) event...

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that in a much simpler manner:

```
<asp:DataList RepeatLayout="Table" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server" ID="dl">
            <ItemTemplate>              
                <uc1:UCGroup ID="UCGroup1" runat="server" Title=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "RecipientGroup.Name") %> />

                    <div class="template_over"> 
                        <a href="/ScheduleCampaign/<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "RecipientGroup.Name") %>">

                      <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Email") %>

                    </a>
                    </div>
              </ItemTemplate>               
            </asp:DataList>
```

---

```
public partial class ChooseGroup : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dl.DataSource = GroupsHndlr.GetExtendedRecipients(MySession.Current.ClientId);
        dl.DataBind();
    }
}
```

---

The code of the control:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbltitle" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

---

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpRecipients" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>   
       1
       </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

---

```
public partial class UCGroup : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<string> Recipients { get; set; }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.lbltitle.Text = Title;
        this.rpRecipients.DataSource = Recipients;
        this.rpRecipients.DataBind();
    }
}
```